# How to get the POST as parameter of a function in Hunchentoot?

Tags: post, common-lisp, sbcl, hunchentoot

I want to use a web formular to filter records stored in mongo-db.

My query function uses a filter as followed:

```
(defun models (filter)
  (docs (db.find *model-collection*
      filter
      :limit 1)))
```

And when I use it in SBCL, it can retrieve the record {"NAME" :"a1"}, with one of the following command:

```
(models ($ "NOM" "a1"))
(models (eval (read-from-string "(kv \"NOM\" \"a1\")")))

(<DOCUMENT> : { 
_id : CL-MONGO::BSON-OID ...elements : 14})
```

Now I add the web interface developed in Hunchentoot, one for the query formular and one to display the response:

```
(define-easy-handler (test :uri "/test") () 
  (with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output* nil :prologue t :indent t)
    (:html 
     (:body
      (:h1 "Test")
      (:form :action "/test1" :method "post" :id "addform"
       (:input :type "text" :name "name" :class "txt")
       (:input :type "submit" :class "btn" :value "Submit"))))))

(define-easy-handler (test1 :uri "/test1") (name)
 (with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output* nil :prologue t :indent t)  
  (:html 
   (:body  
    (:h1 "My List")
       (:p (str (models name)))))))
```

When I enter in the submit form the following filter : ($ "NAME" "a1"),
i get an error at the display page, and the following log in SBCL:

```
compiling (DEFINE-EASY-HANDLER (TEST1 :URI ...) ...)
[2015-02-12 15:41:47 [ERROR]] The value #\( is not of type (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8).

17: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD CL-MONGO:DB.FIND (STRING T))
    #<unused argument>
    #<unused argument>
    "mycollection"
    "($ \"NOM\" \"a1\")"
   :MONGO
   NIL
   :OPTIONS
   0
   :SKIP
   0
   :LIMIT
   1
   :SELECTOR
   NIL)
18: (WEB-TEST::MODELS2 "($ \"NOM\" \"a1\")")
19: (WEB-TEST::TEST1 :NAME NIL)
```

It try several pre transformation in test1 such as:

```
(:p (str (models (eval (read-from-string name)))))
or (:p (str (models (eval (esc name)))))
```

But none of them work properly. Does anyone could advice?

Comment: Perhaps you should also show the error message, not just the stack.

Comment: yes of course. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string to `models`, not a filter produced by `$`.  Using `eval` on external input is a *very bad idea*, too.

You could just pass the name to your handler and build the filter from that:

```
(:p (str (models ($ "NOM" name))))
```

Call your handler with `a1` as `name`.

I would generally not advise to let users pass in arbitrary expressions that hit the database unchecked.

Comment: I found a work arround by inserting something like _(let ((input name)).._ in the handler. But you are probably right, I should revise the way I generate the code in the handler. And I should not let the user hitting directling the database.